# SBT 0.7.x to 0.12.3 upgrade issues

Tags: sbt

I have just taken over a project using SBT 0.7.x and I am trying to convert it to use 0.12.3. The project has config as a *.java file and I can't find where some of the classes/objects that are used were moved to. I found a VERY small table in the migration docs, but is it not complete, for example it says that FileUtilities was moved to IO, which is true only for some of the functions. The following functions/classes/objects are nowhere to be found:

- FileUtilities.copyFlat
- FileUtilities.clean
- Path.lazyPathFinder
- BasicScalaProject
- MavenStyleScalaPaths
- DefaultProject
- ProjectInfo
- IdeaProject

Can someone please tell me where those went or where there is a complete log of changes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete log of changes, but I did write [an unofficial guide to sbt 0.10 v2.0](http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide), which lists some of the changes between 0.7 and modern sbt.